# Use fourier transform to calculate image pixelation coef in python

Tags: image-processing, fourier-transform, python

I want to calculate a coef of image pixelation to remove bad pictures from a bunch of files.

Some pictures results from bad compression and we can see a lot of pixelation on them like img a here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPOBI.jpg

I have heard of Fourier transform to calculate repetitive pattern, maybe it can be used in this case to detect pixel square ?

any kind of code making it possible is welcome.

Comment: Are these images coded using a variety of different techniques or just JPEG (for example)?

Comment: I extract them from videos (mainly encoded with flv and sometime h264) with ffmpeg so I think I can extract them as raw any other formats.

Comment: By "pixelation" you mean lossy compression "jaggy" artifacts?  You mean you want to know which files were compressed at too high of a ratio?  Does the file format store the compression ratio in its metadata?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i filename.flv` says `Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 720x576, 200 kb/s, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc`  "200 kb/s" is what you want to know.  `Stream #0.0(und): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 176x144 [PAR 1:1 DAR 11:9], 270 kb/s, PAR 12:11 DAR 4:3, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 1k tbn, 10 tbc`